# managing large sessions using GAE and VAADIN

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, vaadin

I'm having hard time managing sessions with GAE/J and VAADIN. Facing two problems:

- session is persisted in datastore between requests which gives hard limit of 1MB per session. our startup session is 700K, you can imagine that we can hit that limit pretty soon.
- this definitely becomes performance issue. datastore/memcache session writes cause sometime significant delay which degrades user experience. as a workaround I customizes Vaadin GAE servlet and enforced only async datastore writes instead. this solves the performance problems, but compromises the application state. as a result I sometimes get out of sync screens detecting stale state.

Anyone having similar problems? Or give a solution hint?

===============================================

Wicket have similar problem, found great workaround:

http://blog.small-improvements.com/2012/02/19/reducing-wicket-session-size-to-one-third/

Comment: What on earth are you putting in a session that weighs in at 700k?

Comment: Vaadin persists entire application state in the session

Comment: And what's in the application state? This sounds like a terrible design, and the solution is probably to fix the app.

Comment: Nick, I appreciate your great expertise in the field, but I don't consider your answers as very constructive. I will follow your advice to fix the app, but I have to say that this solution will be workaround of technological constraint introduced by GAE, not as a result of terrible design.

Comment: I'm sorry you don't find my answers constructive, but it's all I can offer. The fact that storing and loading 700k of session data for every request is slow is not a technical limitation - it's simply poor design.

Comment: Not necessarily poor design. If you have sophisticated tools with, say, a JSON representation cached in the session of the apps model, it is possible to have this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that Vaadin stores the entire UI in the session. However, that is not typically too much considered it is only a set of components (Java classes) that are visible to the user. Typically large session size is because of a lot of data is bound to the user interface components.

It is easy to do this, because fields in UI components that point to data objects make them part of the session and it can rapidly become big unless you take care of it properly.

To solve this, you might want to refactor your code a bit to get the session size smaller. In general this means

There is no single recipe for doing this, but here are some starting points:

1. Make sure you are not initializing the whole UI in Application.init() method. Especially postpone the loading of large amounts of data to actually showing the UI and event listeners.
2. Load and bind data when a new view is attached (displayed) in Component.attach() method.
3. Clear data on Component.detach() when it is no longer visible/accessible to the user.

There are also other ways, but with these you should get started with session size optimization.

Comment: thanks, do you have actually hands-on experience solving such a problem or this is suggestion? this refactoring might involve resolving interdependencies between the components, we have to make sure we de-register the detached components as a listeners as well. how about navigator7 add-on? it has very convenient page concept, might be used if it keeps session size small.